# Return an object from a Block to match NS_RETURNS_RETAINED behavior

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

I'm using a block to swizzle a method with `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED` behavior. My program is crashing, presumably because ARC is autoreleasing the return value. Can I add the `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED` attribute to my block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If necessary, you can artificially bump the return value's retain count:

```
^id () {
    void * retained = (__bridge_retained void *)myObject;
    return (__bridge id)retained;
};
```